# how to print all calculated elements vertically after I have finished adding all inputs with a cycle in python?

Tags: python, loops, printing

I have been tried to get the print code out of its loop, but when I do that, it has been caused the program to forgot my j function which has been defined at its previous line. Please help me if anyone can, and thank you in advance.

```
import math

z = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    x = float(input())
    j = math.sqrt(x)
    print('%10.4f' % j)
```

its answer is like this:

```
4
1
    1.0000
2
    1.4142
3
    1.7321
```

however, I want it to be like this:

```
1.0000
1.4142
1.7320
```

Comment: What is `z` in your code?

Comment: it was for a (z.append()) code but I have removed it, so it is redundant now.

Comment: Surely `z.append(...)` is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Append the outputs to an empty list and then print the list.

```
import math
z = []
for i in range(n):
    x = float(input())
    z.append(math.sqrt(x))

for i in z:
  print(i)
```

Output:

```
2.0
1.0
1.4142135623730951
1.7320508075688772
```

Comment: Thank you, I have altered the "print(i)" into "print('%10.4f' % I)" and got the desired results.